# pylons url_for doesn't yield proper internal static. SCRIPT_NAME is not inserted into the resolved URL

Tags: routes, pylons, wsgi

I integrate pylons applications into apache webserver using mod_wsgi. The configuration for wsgi is as such:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /mtrace /var/lib/lgmtrace/lgmtrace.wsgi
```

However, using h.url_for within the mako template doesn't yield proper url for static internal route as described in http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/urls-routing-and-dispatch.html#internal-static-routes. I've checked the environment variable in the **BaseController** of pylons and **SCRIPT_NAME** has been properly set to /mtrace.

So, I decided to look into the code of **url_for** function within the routes package. As it turns out, **environ** attribute was never set for **config** variables returned from **request_config**. As a result, the code that calls for **config.environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME')** was never executed.

I wonder if anyone can help me on this matter because I'm stucked on this problem for quite some time already. Has anyone faces the same situation? How to fix it so that the URL can be resolved correctly. I couldn't find any results for my problem on google and stackoverflow, so I guess it must be some sort of configuration error that leads to this situation. For your information, I use all the default packages provided by Fedora 14 for mod_wsgi (3.2.2), apache server (2.2.17), pylons (1.0), routes (1.12).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Someone suggested me to try Route-1.12.3 to see if the problem is resolved. It wasn't resolved using that version. Heck, work around this problem by prepending request['SCRIPT_NAME'] to the url in the mako template manually. I would like to know if anyone has the proper answer to this question.

Comment: One kind fellow at pylons-discuss group pointed to me that the solution to this is to use url instead of h.url in the mako template. The solution that he suggested works and should be used instead.

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. Note that there is a difference between `h.url("/about")` and `h.url("about")`.